# with RSA encryption, how do I find the md5sum of the private key from the public key?

Tags: encryption, rsa

This is a purely mathematical question on RSA encryption.

Having $e$ as the public key exponent and $n$ the modulus of a public key. Can I recover the md5sum of the private key $d$ (inverse of $d$ according to the modulus.)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Besides the quite obvious issue with regards to recovering the private exponent (or CRT parameters) first, you can only create a hash over a *binary representation* of a key. Sometimes a hash over the modulus of a key pair is used as identifier, you might mean that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From the public key $(n,e)$ can I recover the md5sum of the private key $d$ (inverse of $d$ according to the modulus).

No, because:

1. This quantity is not well-defined for multiple reasons

   - In RSA, $d$ is not the *"inverse of $d$ according to the modulus"*. Common definitions include:

     - $d_\varphi=e^{-1}\bmod\varphi(n)$ where $\varphi(n)$ is [Euler's totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), with $\varphi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)$ when $n$ is the product of two distinct primes.
     - $d_\lambda=e^{-1}\bmod\lambda(n)$ where $\lambda$ is the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function), with $\lambda(n)=\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$ when $n$ is the product of two distinct primes. It holds $\lambda(n)\le\varphi(n)/2$ and often $d_\lambda<d_\varphi$.
     - In the standard definition of RSA ([PKCS#1](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr)), $d$ is any integer $d$ with $0<d<n$ and $e\;d\equiv 1\pmod{\lambda(n)}$. This includes at least $d=d_\lambda$ and $d=d_\lambda+\lambda(n)$, thus $d$ is not uniquely defined.
   - MD5 hashes bitstrings, and it's not specified one of the several representations of the same $d$ as bitstring: the ASN.1 encoding of $d$, a big-endian or little-endian encoding with or without padding to a fixed length.
2. Even if we fix the above (by e.g .asking for the MD5 hash of the shortest bytestring that's a litle-endian binary representation of $d_\lambda$, which is mathematically a computable function of any $(n,e)$ forming a valid public key), it remains that the most efficient known method to compute this function (see below) factors $n$, and is thus impractical for practically useful public keys $(n,e)$.

---

If we can factor $n$, we can efficiently compute $\lambda(n)$. If further $(n,e)$ is a valid public key then we can then efficiently compute the uniquely defined $d=e^{-1}\bmod\lambda(n)$ with $0<d<\lambda(n)$, and efficiently compute its MD5 hash or md5sum using some specified convention.

Comment: I understand it is possible to factore n if we find another key that has the same GCD, is there a tool online that could process that?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot get a hash over the entire private key if you've just got $n$ and $e$. You can however create a hash over the modulus $n$. This is sometimes used as identifier for keys within a *key pair*, e.g. in PKCS#11. Usually SHA-1 is used however, not MD5.

The modulus is unique for RSA key pairs and links the public key and private key together.

`md5sum` is a GNU utility that performs MD5, it's not an algorithm in itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Recovering the md5sum of the private key means uncovering the private key, which is considered impossible for large values of $n$.

Comment: Technically, I am not aware of any *proof* that you can't. It is however *highly* plausible that this is impossible.